# ActionBarSherlock Change Height?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, material-design

I'm trying to change the height of my action bar to give it a more Material feel, but whatever I try never seems to work. Currently I have this:

```
<!-- Main Theme -->
<style name="WPTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/WPTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/WPTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomActionOverflowDropDownText</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/CustomActionOverflowDropDownText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButton</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/black</item>
</style>

<!-- Action Bar Theme -->
<style name="WPTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ic_bar_top</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_bar_top</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">56dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">56dip</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListView.DropDown</item>
</style>
```

Is there any other solutions out there? Or am I just making some bone-head error here that I'm not picking up on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing of height of actionbarsherlock is not the solution.

Use Translucent system bars

You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new themes,

Check this project https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the parent theme or include the [windowTranslucentNavigation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentNavigation) and [windowTranslucentStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowTranslucentStatus) style properties in your theme.

Hope this helps get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Move `<item name="actionBarSize">56dip</item>` and `<item name="android:actionBarSize">56dip</item>` to your main theme.

Also, if you'd like, you can check out my blog post on achieving a material style action bar on older android versions [here](http://xipdev.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/how-to-create-a-material-style-action-bar-on-kitkat-and-older-android-versions/). Though I haven't written it to be used with ActionBarSherlock, with some slight modifications, you should be able to get the same thing working.